# Why don't I see local variables while debugging in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, device

I'm trying to debug an Android app on a device. I expect the local variables to be displayed in the Expressions view in the Debug perspective in Eclipse, but that entire view is empty.

The last message in the console is: `Attempting to connect debugger to 'my.app.id' on port 8601` which seems questionable. I do have debugging enabled on the device, in the manifest, and I have the SET_DEBUG_APP permission included in the manifest.

Why can't I see my local variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variables are normally seen in the 'Variables' view of the debug perspective not the 'Expressions' view. Yours must be closed, so just add it from the menu, with Window, Show View, Variables option.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you. 'Variables' appears in the same spot as Expressions (in this perspective, anyway), and it didn't occur to me that it was a different view.